# Trying to replace new lines between quotes, does not work in one situation

Tags: regex

I have this expression:

```
\n(?!")|\r(?!")|\r\n(?!")
```

What is it about the second situation that causes this to not work? The only thing I can figure out is that the line feed is right in front of the quote character, but I am not sure if that is the problem and how to fix it if is is.

Which works in this first situation:

```
"abcdef"
"ghilmn"
"opq
rst"
```

becomes

```
"abcdef"
"ghilmn"
"opqrst"
```

It does not work in this second situation:

```
"abcdef"
"ghilmn"
"opq
rst
"
```

becomes

```
"abcdef"
"ghilmn"
"opqrst
"
```

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: I am using this regex in notepad++ so I think the answer is general text editor flavor. For things that get complicated I am using sed and awk, so staying within text editor capabilities should work for me.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a regular expression only matches once. Look up the `global` flag and how to apply it in whichever environment you are running this - usually something like `/expression/g`.

Comment: that is interesting and it makes sense, but I am running this in notepad++ and I cannot seem to find documentation regarding the global flag in that program

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for search:

```
\n(?!(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

and use an empty string as replacement.

This regex uses a negative lookahead to assert we don't have even number of quotes ahead of newline character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8ADCQ/1)

Comment: This does what I need it to do in notepad++ but I need to run it over and over again. I cannot figure out how to get it to work in cygwin. But it gets me where I need to go so that is great!